# watir webdriver unable to click button in the table

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

```
<tr class="even_row">
    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
        <button type="button" onclick="doSubmit('_eventId_addToHouseholdFromOther')">
            <span>
                <i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>
            </span>
        </button>
    </td>
    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"> … </td>
    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"> … </td>
    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1"> … </td>
</tr>
```

Does anybody know, how I can click on this button using watir webdriver?

Comment: Is the problem with locating the button? Is the button unique (ie is there only one left arrow button) or how do you, as a user, know which button to click?

Comment: Yes, it is unique, but it does not have any id, so I don't find any method how I can click on it.
I tried this, but it does not work.
f.button.div(:id, 'householdToHouseholdDialog').tables(:index => 1).span(:class => 'icon-arrow-left').click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `<i class="icon-arrow-left">` element is unique (ie no other i element with the same class exists), you can do:

```
browser.i(:class => 'icon-arrow-left').click
```